# PHP export MySQL to xml non English characters in browser displayed as `?`

Tags: php, mysql, xml

With php need to export mysql data to xml. I know about `htmlspecialchars` (in case of `print/echo`); will do that latter.

Now question is how to correctly display non English characters.

MySQL encoding is 'UTF-8'.

In MySQL non English characters are displayed correctly.

This is my code

```
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-Type: text/xml');

//.... mysql connect, select

$DOM = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$root = $DOM->createElement('корневой');
$DOM->appendChild($root);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
$child11 = $DOM->createElement('вложенный',mb_convert_encoding($row['TransactionPartnerName'], "UTF-8") );
$root->appendChild($child11);
$child_att11 = $DOM->createAttribute('vārds');
$child11->appendChild($child_att11);
$att_text11 = $DOM->createTextNode('Value attribute11');
$child_att11->appendChild($att_text11);
}

echo $DOM->saveXML();
```

Non English characters here `$root = $DOM->createElement('корневой');` in browser displays correctly.

But this `$child11 = $DOM->createElement('вложенный',mb_convert_encoding($row['TransactionPartnerName'], "UTF-8") );` displays `?` instead of non English characters (I mean this `вложенный` displayed correctly, but instead of non English characters from this `$row['TransactionPartnerName']` get `?`).

Before there was `$child11 = $DOM->createElement('child11',$row['TransactionPartnerName']);` and get `An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource` in IE.

When added `mb_convert_encoding` no warnings, but displayed `?`.

Tried to experiment and save. Changed to `$DOM->save("test1.xml");` And test1.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<корневой>
<вложенный vārds="Value attribute11">AUTOMOTIVE</вложенный>
<вложенный vārds="Value attribute11">???????</вложенный>
</корневой>
```

You see `???????` and in MySQL is `русский` instead of these `?`.

Any ideas how display/save correctly non English characters?

**Update**
According to advice after `mysql_connect` added

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

and all works. OK with MySQL, but for PDO as I understand must use other code. In any case seems can understand where was problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_set_charset('utf8')` to get UTF-8 encoded results from the db.